# Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree. But I want to listen to it

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-provider

I am trying to listen for updates made to a string variable in my provider model. Flutter is suggesting that I do not listen to them as the listener is apparently out of the widget tree context and I can't see why.

My widget I am calling the listener on is an IconButton which resides in a Stateful widget class that is a part of a list item of many others items that goes into a ListView builder. I am wanting to get the string from the listener and then call setState in the Stateful widget class to update the list item only from the list item that had its IconButton pressed. I do not want to update every list item in the ListView builder. Otherwise I would of put the listener on the Text field directly. Hope that makes sense.. :)

```dart
IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
    onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<VoiceFunctions>(context, listen: false).startFirstVoiceListener();
        var newWords = Provider.of<VoiceFunctions>(context, listen: true).outputString;
        print(newWords);
}),
```

I've tried moving the listener for outputString into its own function so its out of the onPressed() but that gives the same error.

The full stack trace:

```dart
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree.

This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called
Provider.of without passing `listen: false`.

To fix, write:
Provider.of<VoiceFunctions>(context, listen: false);

It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the
event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.

The context used was: FlashcardItemWidget(dependencies: [MediaQuery, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#02e26], _InheritedTheme], state: _FlashcardItemWidgetState#51c99)
'package:provider/src/provider.dart':
Failed assertion: line 191 pos 7: 'context.owner.debugBuilding ||
          listen == false ||
          debugIsInInheritedProviderUpdate'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to:**

```dart
Provider.of<VoiceFunctions>(context, listen: false);
```